# Mongoose model values being returned as a string instead of an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model that has some nested properties. When I query for a document using this model, the document is returned but I can only access the properties two levels deep, sometimes. Other nested objects are returned as something other than an object whose properties i can access with dot notation, I can't figure out why.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    settings: {
        some_settings: {
            enabled: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 1, default: 0 },
            interval: { type: Number, min: 0, default: 30 }, // seconds
            start_diff: { type: Number, min: 0, default: 3600 } // seconds
        },
        other_settings: {
            push_settings: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 1, default: 1, sparse: true }
        }
    }
});
```

When I get this returned after a `findOne` query and run `settings.other_settings.push_settings`, this returns undefined even though the value is in the database. But if I `console.log(settings.other_settings)` the console prints out the correct values, but they can't be accessed. It's as if mongoose isn't recognizing that this nested object exists.

**EDIT**: The document I receive after running findOne prints to the console like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    settings: {
        some_settings: { enabled: 1, interval: 30, start_diff: 3600 },
        other_settings: { push_settings: 1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the document you're getting with `findOne`?

Comment: Sure, I added the document that prints out.

Comment: Hmm...it works fine when I try it with that doc. Can you edit your question to include the code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: After messing with my model more, it seemed like the order in which the properties were written mattered. If i reversed some_settings with other_settings, it would start working. Very strange. I'm going to assume it was an index or another issue in the DB since everyone here seems to have it working fine. I was able to solve the problem by switching the order of my properties.